# How do I create a numerical list, and then replace the odd numbers in the list with first even numbers higher than them?

Tags: python, replace, numbers, python-idle

For example: `([3,85,44,71,9,5])` would return `([4,86,44,72,10,6])`

The user inputs the information, so would I have to create an empty list?

Lots of help would be appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = [3,85,44,71,9,5]
list2 = [x + (x%2) for x in list1]
```

noting that `x%2` is 1 for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers.

Comment: probably your solution is more elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

Using lambda and ternary operator:

```
list1 = [3,85,44,71,9,5]
map(lambda x: x if x%2==0 else x+1, list1) 
[4, 86, 44, 72, 10, 6]
```

P.S. Related discussion: [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: tips: (1) don't name variables the same as built-ins (`list` is a built-in function), (2) use list comprehensions instead of `map` where possible because list comprehensions are faster and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = []
num = 0
while (num != -1):
   num = input("Enter number; enter -1 to end: ")
   if (num != -1):
      list.append(num+1)
```

Comment: This describes how to make a list from user input, but not how to increment the odd numbers.

Comment: That's true.. doesn't the original question state that the user inputs the information?

Comment: It's not clear _how_ the user inputs the information. Lacking that, it's hard to recommend a particular approach. (Your code is reasonable but not too Pythonic; I would recommend just using an infinite loop and a `break`, and losing the parentheses around the `while` and `if` conditions).

Answer (score 0):

Use `modulo`:

```
arr = [3,85,44,71,9,5]
arr = [item + item%2 for item in arr]
```

This runs as:

```
>>> arr = [3,85,44,71,9,5]
>>> arr = [item + item%2 for item in arr]
>>> arr
[4, 86, 44, 72, 10, 6]
>>>
```

`%` works as such:

```
>>> 9%2 #Gives 1, because 9/2 is 4 remainder 1
1
>>> 10%2 #Gives 0, because 10/2 is 5 remainder 0
0
>>>
```